# How do I create a channel in Pusher

Tags: pusher

I could not find any explicit information about the creation of channels with Pusher.
Is that simply an implicit action when either subscribing on the client or pushing events on the server?

```
class HelloController < ApplicationController
  def hello
    #does this create a channel "named 'test-channel'"?
    Pusher['test-channel'].trigger('test_event', { :hello => 'world' })
  end
end
```

If so is there a limit to the number of channels available?

The reason for my question is that I'd like to create a unique channel for every user and after the client side has closed down that channel.

But probably that is not really a good idea ;-)

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Channels are really just a way of routing or filtering data. They exist by simply being subscribed to or having data published to them. So, it is an implicit action.

There are no limits to the number of channels you use and a unique channel per user is a nice solution for targeted messaging.